# asp.net Label cannot ever be modified from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, updatepanel

I have a panel/updatepanel that contains an asp.net label.  It seems that under no circumstances whatsoever the Text field of this control can be changed.  Code:

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" Width="100%">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updRouteGroup" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDisableOnHold" />
      </Triggers>
      <ContentTemplate>        
       <asp:Panel ID="pnlImpExcel" runat="Server" >
      <div style="width:100%">
       <table colspan="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
             <th colspan="3">
                On Hold Music
             </th>
          </tr>
          <tr style="height:10px"></tr>
          <tr>
             <td align="left" valign="middle" style="width:33%"><div id="fine-uploader"></div></td>
             <td align="center" valign="middle"><asp:Label ID="lblOnHoldFile" runat="server" Text="Current file: none" /></td>
             <td align="right" valign="middle"><asp:Button ID="btnDisableOnHold" runat="server" style="margin-right:7px;width:87px;" Text="Disable Hold Music" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnDisableOnHold_OnClick" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan ="2" align="center"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblUploadError" style="color: Red;" Visible="false" /></td></tr>
       </table>              
       </div>
       </asp:Panel> 
       </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
    </asp:Panel>
```

When a postback occurs I might need to update this, so I check some conditions and then attempt to modify the text by doing:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Page.IsPostBack)
       lblOnHoldFile.Text = "Some text.";
}
```

This code is probably bad, I've little experience with ASP.NET and have inherited this project.  But I still cannot understand what the point of exposing these labels in the code-behind is if you cannot modify them at all.  How can I set the .Text field of the control lblOnHoldFile?  Thanks.

Here is what's in btnDisableHold_OnClick:

```
  protected void btnDisableOnHold_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     //Update some records

     // Clear out any existing file from the label:
     lblOnHoldFile.Text = "Current file: none";
  }
```

Comment: Well, how are you trying to change it ? Can you show us your code-behind ?

Comment: Of course I forget to add a critical detail.  I've just added this to the post in an edit.

Comment: There might be something else messing up your code, code this worked for me when clicked on the button to cause a postback.

Comment: How is the postback being triggered?

Comment: @HanletEscaño But I want to change the value of lblOnHoldFile when something other than the button is clicked.  I need to be able to change it whenever.

Comment: @KarlAnderson The postback is triggered by the btnDisableHold (also in that update panel) getting clicked.  The problem is I need to be able to set lblOnHoldFile at any time in Page_Load, not just when that button is clicked.

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else. I used the exact code (adding a script manager to the page and blank click event) and it worked on the first try.

Comment: @kmarks2 maybe you need to read a little on the life cycle of your page. Page_Onload will happens when the page is loaded, if you want to change the text on any other event you should be able to.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Is there someway I can force that panel to update in my Page_Load?  I ask because I want to trigger a postback when a a javascript third part control (inside the div) does something.  But because it is not an asp.net control (it's javascript) I cannot use it as an update trigger.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Added that on click code to the original post.

Comment: @kmarks2 - see my answer for an explanation of why it appears that setting the `Text` property does nothing.

Comment: @kmarks2 You're changing the text back in the button click event. Not sure why. But that's your reason.

Comment: @KevinDeVoe No, because I am not clicking the btnDisableHold.  I am trying to set this label in a completely different use case involving a different control.  The btnDisableHold_OnClick is not executed at all.

Comment: @kmarks2 How are you trying to set the label? Is the page being reloaded? If it's a partial postback you may not get the same behavior as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is your problem, this line:

```
lblOnHoldFile.Text = "Current file: none";
```

You have undone the text change you made in `Page_Load` with the above line in your click event handler.

The `Text` property of your label got changed twice; once to `Some text` in the `Page_Load` and then back to its original value in `btnDisableOnHold_OnClick` method. This makes it appear that setting the `Text` value does nothing, when in reality it was changed.

UPDATE:

To have JavaScript create a postback for your code, then you need to invoke the `__doPostBack` function.

Read [Understanding the JavaScript __doPostBack Function](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function)

Comment: I am trying to update this label at times when the btnDisableHold has not even been clicked, so that code does not execute in the case I'm trying for.

Comment: What other code? You only have one button in your code and it is calling the line referenced in my answer.

Comment: In the markup I posted, in addition to the button, there is a div.  Populated to this div is some javascript for the third part FineUploader control.  I want to trigger a postback when the FineUploader related javascript in that div does something.  But you cannot but a reference to javascript or a div as a Postback trigger.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `updRouteGroup.Update()` after the line where you change the text of the label.
This line with an explicit call is needed as the Label is inside an `UpdatePanel` with `UpdateMode Conditional`. It should not be required when the button `btnDisableOnHold`  is clicked though.

Or else just change the `UpdateMode` to `Always` and that should work.

To read more about the `Update Panels` and their `UpdateMode` Property, check this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx

Comment: I tried calling .Update but this did not work.  I also tried setting mode to Always, which also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

kmarks2,

**Your markup:**

`<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="someLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>

</asp:Content>`

**C# Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        someLabel.Text = "This is text generated from code-behind, in c#";
    }
```

Comment: This is basically what I have done, except it's in a ContentTemplate.  It still does not work.  I can step through with the debugger and gaurantee the line executes, it just never actually does anything.

Comment: Ah, sorry. You hadn't updated your OP with much code at the time, didn't know.